# How can I make the layout_width of a MaterialTextView in XML expand beyond the screen boundaries using XML only?

Tags: android, xml

```
<com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/txt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:text="Helloooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo" />
```

I am trying to create a MaterialTextView in my XML layout that will display text on a single line. Currently, the layout_width of this MaterialTextView is set to wrap_content, but I want it to continue expanding even if it extends beyond the screen boundaries.

**The current result is that the MaterialTextView's width stops at the edge of the screen.**

[image]

**The desired result is for the MaterialTextView's width to continue expanding, regardless of the screen boundaries.**

[image]

How can I achieve this using XML only?

Comment: Why do you want this? What is the containing _ViewGroup_? _LinearLayout_ or other?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using some parent view that actually extends on screen as you want regardless the screen boundaries.

This worked for me:

```
        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="none">

            <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                android:id="@+id/txt"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="Helloooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo" />
        </HorizontalScrollView>
```

And for this particular case maybe you can disable the scroll if that doesn't fit your goal.

Preview XML:

[Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hhTs.png)